# Multiple inheritance pointers & cast

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
namespace Try {

class Point2d {
    float _x, _y;
public:
    Point2d(float x, float y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
};

class Vertex {
    Vertex* next;
public:
    Vertex(Vertex* n) : next(n) {}
    Vertex() {}
};

class Vertex2d : public Point2d, public Vertex {
    float mumble;
public:
    Vertex2d(float x, float y, float mum) : Point2d(x,y), mumble(mum) {}
};
}

int main (void)
{
using Try::Point2d;
using Try::Vertex;
using Try::Vertex2d;

Vertex2d v3d(2.5,3,4);
Vertex*  pv;
Point2d* pp;

pv = &v3d;      
pv = (Vertex*)(((char*)&v3d) + sizeof(Point2d));
}
```

Does anyone mind explaining me why the last two commands:

```
pv = &v3d;
pv = (Vertex*)(((char*)&v3d) + sizeof(Point2d));
```

(I guess that that is what the compiler translates the pv = &v3d to..)

are completely identical? I can understand the (+sizeof(Point2d)) is there because the Vertex2d is Point2d first so we have to add the size in order to reach the "Vertex" part.
but why does it cast v3d to char* first..?

thanks

Comment: They are not identical. One is legal C++, the other invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior why?

Comment: According to 5.7/5, "If both the pointer operand and the result [of a pointer arithmetic expression] point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined".
In addition, the behavior is "unspecified" according 5.2.10/7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why does it cast v3d to char* first..?

`sizeof` produces a measurment in *bytes*, and `sizeof(char)` is `1` byte, so the pointer math performed by `(some_char_pointer) + sizeof(Point2d)` will be correct.

*(A relevent pointer math review:)*

Assume for the sake of illustration that `sizeof(Point2d)` is `16`.  This expression...

```
&v3d + sizeof(Point2d)
```

...would **not** point 16 *bytes* after `&v3d`.  It would point **16 `Vertex2d`s** after `&v3d`.  Or `16 * sizeof(Vertex2d)` bytes.

Comment: @Rouki - don't worry about it. That last line is nonsense.

Comment: Ehm, Let me see if I understand it correctly. It first casts the the v3d address to char* , by doing that it now "sees" that memory chunk as a CHAR, which is one byte. adding to that the size of (point2d) will lead us to the vertex part directly. is that correct +-?

Comment: @Rouki You seem to understand it now.  Adding a number to a pointer does not always add that many *bytes*.  It depends on the size of the type pointed to.